# Comparing ArrayLists

Tags: java, indexing, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, genetic-algorithm

I have a program that seats people based on their preference to seat next to to other people. They are seated at tables with a set number of seats. Each Seat at the table then has a Person assigned to it, that Person has a list of preferences of whom they would like to sit next to. The preferences are valued from 1-6.

ex)

Bob is at seat 1, 
He has a preference to sit next to Jill,

and that preference is rated 6. He really wants to sit next to her.

Jill is at seat 2,

She has a preference to sit next to Bob which is rated 6 also.

Josh is at seat 3,

He has a preference to sit next to David, who is not at the table. (His preference score will not be counted)

Peter is at the final seat, seat 4.

His preferences are Josh, with a value of 3, and Bob, with a value of 5.

What is a good way of going about on how to check if a Name in the preferences of a Person is at the table using ArrayLists?

This is what I have come up with

```
for (int i = 0; i < seatsList.size(); i++) { // For the seats at the table
    for (int j = 0; j < seatsList.get(i).getPrefArrayList().size(); j++) { // For the prefList for each seat                            
        if(seatsList.get(i).getPrefArrayList().contains(seatsList.get(j).getName())){ 
            //score += seatsList.get(i).getOnePrefValue(j); //IGNORE THIS LINE FOR NOW(NOT REALLY IMPORTANT)
        }           
    }           
}
```

`seatsList` is an ArrayList that holds all the seats.

`getPrefArrayList()` returns an ArrayList of all the preferences of THAT person.

`getName()` will just return the name of a Person at a specific seat

In this example, the outer loop will iterate through the seats at the table. The inner loop will iterate through the preferences of each Person(or seat) at the table. Since some people will have more preferences than others, the inner loop will have no constant amount of iterations. It will vary depending on the Person's preferences.

The problem with this example is Line 3, within the if-statement

```
seatsList.get(j).getName()
```

Since there is a chance that the amount of preferences a person would have is longer than the amount of seats at the table, you would get an index out of bounds error.

Is there anyway that I could do this? This meaning, find out if **any** preference of a Person is sitting at the table with them. The answer is probably right in my face. If anyone is curious, it's for a school assignment involving Genetic Algorithms.

Comment: Do you want to know if _any_ of a person's preferences are seated at the table with them?  Or do you want to know if _all_ of there preferences are at the table with them?

Comment: @Quicksilver002 Any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for(Seat seat : seatsList){ //or whatever object type is in seatsList
  boolean seatHasPreferenceAtTable = false;
  for(Preference preference : seat.getPrefArrayList()){//or whatever object type is in getPrefArrayList()
    for(Seat otherSeat : seatsList){
      if(otherSeat.getName().equals(preference.getName())){
        seatHasPreferenceAtTable = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Kinda rough, but that should work.